# Implement inertia in custom scroll in SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-scrollview

In my Android game I have implemented a custom code in the `onTouchEvent` method of a (custom) `SurfaceView` to emulate a `ScrollView`. I already tried an actual `ScrollView`, but due to performance and lack of customizability I preferred to override `onTouchEvent` myself.

It works perfectly, but I cannot properly emulate the inertia effect typical of scrollviews.
What I did right now is this:

```
int beginRawY = 0;
int beginScrollValue = 0;
Integer firstPointerId = null;

[...]

private boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        int index = event.getActionIndex();
        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);
        int rawY = (int) event.getRawY();

        // This is meant to deal with multitouch: scroll only if I'm using "the same finger".
        boolean rightPointer = firstPointerId != null && firstPointerId == pointerId;

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initVelocityTracker(event);
                if(firstPointerId == null) {
                    // Save initial scrollValue and touch position
                    beginRawY = rawY;
                    beginScrollValue = scrollValue;
                    firstPointerId = pointerId;
                    return true;
                }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                if(rightPointer) {
                    updateVelocity(event);
                    // Updates scroll value to new scroll value
                    scrollValue = beginScrollValue -rawY + beginRawY;
                    return true;
                }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                if(rightPointer) {
                    //Start the Dissipator runnable, passing to it the speed of the player's touch (number of pixels in 30 milliseconds)
                    dissipator.setVelocity(updateVelocity(event).pixelY());
                    dissipator.run();
                    firstPointerId = null;
                    return true;
                }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void initVelocityTracker(MotionEvent event) {
        if(mVelocityTracker == null) {
            // Retrieve a new VelocityTracker object to watch the velocity of a motion.
            mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
        }
        else {
            // Reset the velocity tracker back to its initial state.
            mVelocityTracker.clear();
        }
        // Add a user's movement to the tracker.
        mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
    }

    private PixelDot updateVelocity(MotionEvent event) {
        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());
        mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
        mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(30);
        return new PixelDot(
                VelocityTrackerCompat.getXVelocity(mVelocityTracker, pointerId),
                VelocityTrackerCompat.getYVelocity(mVelocityTracker, pointerId));
    }

[...]

private class DissipatorRunnable implements Runnable {
    private float velocity = 0;

    public void setVelocity(float velocity) {
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Simply linear descreasing of the scroll speed

        float vValue = velocity;
        if(velocity > 0) {
            while (vValue > 0 && scrollValue > 0) {
                scrollValue = scrollValue - vValue;
                vValue -= 5;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else {
            while (vValue < 0  && scrollValue < height) {
                scrollValue = scrollValue - vValue;
                vValue += 5;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code is simplier than it looks:

I use a ScrollValue to represent "how much the player scrolled". It is the number of pixels.

On Touch Down a save th eposition of the finger and the actual scrollvalue. I initialize a VelocityTracker too.

On Touch Move I update the velocity tracker and the scrollvalue.

On Touch Up I start a custom Runnable called Dissipator:

Every tot milliseconds I reduce (or increment) scrollvalue by the last tracked velocity, and then reduce the velocity value.

This kinda works, but the effect doesn't look like a scrollview with proper inertia, inertia is instead silly and too strong.

What should I do to emulate standard scrollviews inertia?